# Delete Mutiple ListView SelectedItems in code behind with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, entity-framework-core

I have a ListView that displays TitleName from Title table\entity.
Upon ListView_OnSelectionChanged, I can Linq query and display a TitlesDetails Panel, and make visible another panel for edit and delete. But I can only delete one item.
I've google and tried all I could till frustrated and backed off for few days.
  Truly, I'd be happy just to get the Multiple SelectedItems from the ListView into just any list/collection, so I can then do whatever with multiple.
  But if someone showed me how to just get the selectedItems from ListView, I can delete them. I just need them out of the ListView and put into a list/collection I can work with.
I could then understand the thing 'I clearly don't know'
     Can't Cast from this, can't cast to that. Too many variations I've tried to pin point, as I may be using wrong approach all together.

Ok, Mr. ListView can I just please have the SelectedItems and show me how to just put them in any kind of list? So I can play with them from there?
Delete them, manipulate them, even add them to a TitlePlayList table someday!

Xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="ShowTitlesListView" Background="WhiteSmoke" 
                  MinHeight="10" Height="200" MaxHeight="500"
                  Margin="5 7 5 3" 
                  DataContext="{Binding Title}"
                  SelectionMode="Extended"
                  KeyUp="ShowTitlesListView_KeyUp"
                  SelectionChanged="ShowTitlesListView_OnSelectionChanged">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0 0">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 1">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="tbTitleName" Text="{Binding TitleName}"
                                       FontSize="14"
                                       TextWrapping="NoWrap"                                                                      
                                       Margin="2 1"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

My Model if needed to see:

```
...DB Context...  
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
public DbSet<Title> Titles { get; set; }

 ...Tables\Entities...

public class User
{
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserLogin { get; set; }
        public string UserPwd { get; set; }      
        public List<Title> Titles { get; set; } 
        public override string ToString()
        {         
            return UserId + " " + UserLogin + " ";
        }
}
public class Title
{
        public int TitleId { get; set; }
        public string TitleName { get; set; }
        public string TtsRaw { get; set; }
        public string DirPath { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {          
            return UserId + TitleId + TitleName;
        }
}
```

my Code Behind - * It is clear I'm missing a concept, so keep that in mind if you would!

EDIT: Adding -The Listview.ItemSource is in Page_Loaded(...) as below

```
    //LOADING DATA from Database Provider - SQLite - EF Core 5
    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {             
        #region Show current users titles
        using (var context = new PRSappContext())
        {
            var usersTitles =
               from t in context.Titles
               where t.UserId == CurrentUserId
               orderby t.TitleId descending
               select t;

            List<Title> selectedUsersTitles = usersTitles.ToList(); 

            ShowTitlesListView.ItemsSource = selectedUsersTitles;
        }
```

...

```
    private void ShowTitlesListView_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (ShowTitlesListView.SelectedItems.Count > 1)
        {
            ((Title)ShowTitlesListView.SelectedItems);
```

When I try above line, I get below exception
'Exception User-Handlded'
System.InvalidCastException
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'PRSapp.Model.Title'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.
  Source=PRSapp.UWP
  StackTrace:
   at PRSapp.UWP.MainPage.ShowTitlesListView_OnSelectionChanged(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\Flazz\source\repos\FebOn\00MarchRepo\PRSapp\PRSapp.UWP\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 412

```
        if (ShowTitlesListView.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            Title selectedTitleID = ((Title)ShowTitlesListView.SelectedItem);
            int _selectedTitleID = selectedTitleID.TitleId;
            //Get public Title Id for Deleting a single and user forgets to select it
            SelectedTitleId = selectedTitleID.TitleId;

            using (var context = new PRSappContext())
            {
                var usersTitleDetails =
                   from t in context.Titles
                   where t.TitleId == selectedTitleID.TitleId
                   select t;

                List<Title> selectedUsersTitles = usersTitleDetails.ToList();

                TitleDetailsListView.ItemsSource = selectedUsersTitles;
                TitleDetailsListView.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }

        }
```

}

Comment: So, what's your question? If you want to know how to get the selected items. You could use `ListView.SelectedItems` like you have done in above code.

Comment: Thanks for response. Only in the commented out code did I try ListView.SelectedItems. But since there are multiple items selected, do I not need to grab those items and put them into a list?  Yes  Xavier Xie, ListView.SelectedItem (w/o) the 's' is working fine for a single selected item.

Comment: 'But since there are multiple items selected, do I not need to grab those items and put them into a list?' Sorry, I did not quite understand what you say. What exactly was your problem? If you want to get multiple selected items, please use ListView.SelectedItems, if you want to get single selected item, please use ListView.SelectedItem

Comment: I edit it to show there error message I get when I try and cast to get selected items.  ((Title)ShowTitlesListView.SelectedItems);

Comment: You bind ListView's `DataContext="{Binding Title}"`. Where's the ItemsSource that you need to bind? I did not understand what you're doing.

Comment: ItemSource is in Page Loaded(...){   ShowTitlesListView.ItemsSource = db.Titles.ToList(); }, as I also edit above to show. Yes, that would be helpful when asking for help!

Comment: I am thinking the change tracking of the title model by EF Core, is making it so I cannot do anything with SelectedItems. I will test this theory by trying it w/o EF tracking the title model.